# If I apply local group policy for the first time why it is not taking effect untill I restart the machine?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I applied local group policy (Computer Configuration - Software Restriction Policy) but policy is not taking effect. I tried this on domain member (machine is in connection with Domain Controller) and on workgroup machine also.

I used `gpupdate`, `gpupdate /force`, `gpupdate /force /boot`, nothing is working.

I can see the rule in `rsop.msc` also. But policy is not taking effect until I restart the machine once.

After policy got applied if I modify anything or add other rule they take effect immediately, Why is that so? Can I apply local group policy without restarting?

Comment: What does the output of `gpupdate /force` say? Does it tell you that you need to reboot to apply? Some programs read their configuration at start up, `gpupdate` does not particularly notify programs to reload their configuration.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, that would be the expected behavior.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507878.aspx

"You need to reboot the machine to enforce software restriction policies when Software Restriction Policies are created for the first time"

Comment: Thanks Greg, I have another question related to Software Restriction policy,through SRP why can't we block System level application ? Is there any way through which we can block System level application ?